# Compiling FORTRAN code with Graphic Kernel System (GKS) on a cluster

Tags: compilation, makefile, fortran

I am trying to compile a US Geological Survey code called MODPATH, on the University of Colorado computing cluster.  A link to the code is here: http://water.usgs.gov/software/MODPATH/.

The readme file says:

```
In general, to compile a new version of the software, you will need:

    a) a Fortran compiler,
    b) a minimal level of knowledge of Make, the compiler, and
       the UNIX operating system, and
    c) a Graphical Kernel System (GKS) library; GKS libraries
       available without fee include GLI/GKS (available from
       http://iff001.iff.kfa-juelich.de/gli/) and xgks (available
       as the file ftp://unidata.ucar.edu/pub/xgks/xgks-2.5.5.tar.Z).
```

I changed the compiler command to `gfortran`, and upon running `make`, I got the error:

```
    gfortran: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-nolib’
```

I was thinking that error had to do with my compiler.  Also, I am concerned about this GKS business, because (i) I do not want to use the graphic capabilities of this code, I am just running the code as part of a larger optimization routine, and (ii) all the links to download GKS are dead.

Any help about my compiler or GKS issues is greatly appreciated!

Finally, the default makefile options are below:

```
   # Fortran compiler flags (Solaris):
   #   -O - optimization
   # (Note: set FFLAGS to: OptM to generate optimized code
   #                       DbgF to generate debug code)
   DG      = -O -save
   Solaris = -O 
   SGI     = -O -32 -static
   OptM    = $(Solaris)
   DbgF    = -C -g
   FFLAGS  = $(OptM)

   # Compiler name
   FC     = f90

   # GKS libraries:
   XGks     = -L/usr/opt/xgks/lib -lxgks
   GliGks   = -L/usr/local/lib -lgks
   LGks     = $(GliGks)

   # GKS-implementation-specific routines:
   XGksObj  = gkslev2b.o gkscus.o utilgks.o
   GliObj   = gkslev0a.o gkscus.o gqcr.o utilgli.o
   GksObj   = $(GliObj)
```

Comment: Where does the `-nolib' come from? It is not something gfortran would understand. You have to understand the options from the Makefile and change them to the gfortran equivalents.

Comment: You need to look at the $(EXE) and $(EXE2) section of the makefile.  There are many Sun specific options there like -nolib, -Bstatic, -Bdynamic, -lsunmath.  The part that says **You should not need to modify anything below this line**.  All these need to be removed or replaced by the gfortran or ld equivalents.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I guess the main part of my question (and I should have been more clear about it) is if someone can tell me something about this GKS library -- the references on the internet seem to be outdated and unclear, at least as far as I could find.